# Anything wrong with using port 80 for a website?

Tags: website

Is the only reason not to use port 80 the one outlined [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en)?

> 7. If your computer isn't running a webserver, and you haven't set AccountingMax, please consider changing your ORPort to 443 and/or your DirPort to 80. **Many Tor users are stuck behind firewalls that only let them browse the web, and this change will let them reach your Tor relay.** If you are already using ports 80 and 443, other useful ports are 22, 110, and 143.

Comment: Yes. Any port of your choosing is fine but it can be helpful to some users to use the common one. It's entirely up to the relay operator what ports they want to use, so if you've a webserver on 80/443 already that's not a problem and won't conflict with being a relay, just pick another two ports for your relay.

Answer (score -1):

Actually - in a "scanhole case", when DPI is inspecting truly **every** connection - using standart ports will have a good advantage. If port 80 connections are deeply inspected - then it will be easy to detect/suspect Tor usage on it.

Comment: You under stand that, by it's very definition, DPI till know that it's Tor traffic no matter what the port, right? So if it's "inspecting truly **every** connection" it will know what is and isn't Tor?

Comment: in h/w or hw-accelerated implementation - yes, indeed. Sometimes - it's a common case in Russia, for example - it's just a server with software implementation, and ports listened/inspected are specified. In that case it is not inspecting every connection(because it's too resource-expensive for software-only case) and some difference is in place. But in common and proper implementation case it is a full-scale inspection exactly as you've mentioned.